# json object adds additional quotes to object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following string:

`issues = "<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123' target='_blank'>'abc-123'</a>","<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/xyz-456' target='_blank'>'xyz-456'</a>"`

I want to pass this in exactly to the following payload:

```
payload = { 
    "details": {    
        "JIRA Issues": issues
    }, 
    "user":"Monitoring Script", 
    "source":"AWS Lambda", 
    "note":"Action executed via Alert API" 
}
```

i.e., the end result I'm looking for is:

```
payload = { 
    "details": {    
        "JIRA Issues": "<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123' target='_blank'>'abc-123'</a>","<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/xyz-456' target='_blank'>'xyz-456'</a>"
    }, 
    "user":"Monitoring Script", 
    "source":"AWS Lambda", 
    "note":"Action executed via Alert API" 
}
```

However, when I do `print(payload)` I get:

```
{'details': {'JIRA Issues': '"<a href=\'https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123\' target=\'_blank\'>\'abc-123\'</a>","<a href=\'https://jira.abc.com/browse/xyz-456\' target=\'_blank\'>\'xyz-456\'</a>"'}, 'user': 'Monitoring Script', 'source': 'AWS Lambda', 'note': 'Action executed via Alert API'}
```

*Note the extra surrounding `'`*

If I do `print(json.dumps(payload))`, I get:

```
{"details": {"JIRA Issues": "\"<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123' target='_blank'>'abc-123'</a>\",\"<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/xyz-456' target='_blank'>'xyz-456'</a>\""}, "user": "Monitoring Script", "source": "AWS Lambda", "note": "Action executed via Alert API"}
```

What can I do to get the desired output?

Comment: Note that `"JIRA Issues": "<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123' target='_blank'>'abc-123'</a>","<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/xyz-456' target='_blank'>'xyz-456'</a>"` is invalid JSON: you have a standalone comma outside a list, and the next item is not an object item, but a plain string. Do you want a list there, or should the two items be one string?

Comment: What is `issues`? Is it a list or a string? Do you perhaps want the output to be `"JIRA Issues": ["<a href...</a>", "..."]`?